# How to change the background image on your landing page in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I would like to change-replace the default (green) background image shown on my Docusaurus landing page.

Is there a way to do this in a simple way, given that I have limited experience with CSS & Javascript?

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the classic preset to your `docusaurus.config.js`, and configure a `custom.css` file to be used.

```
module.exports = {
    // […]
    presets: [
     [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        // […]
        theme: {
          customCss: [require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css')],
        },
      },
     ],
    ],
};
```

Then go to the `custom.css` file and add the following lines.

**NOTE:** If the the css file doesn't exist, create a it at: `src/css/custom.css` — and create the directories, if necessary.

```
:root {
  --ifm-color-primary: #25c2a0;
  --ifm-color-primary-dark: rgb(33, 175, 144);
  --ifm-color-primary-darker: rgb(31, 165, 136);
  --ifm-color-primary-darkest: rgb(26, 136, 112);
  --ifm-color-primary-light: rgb(70, 203, 174);
  --ifm-color-primary-lighter: rgb(102, 212, 189);
  --ifm-color-primary-lightest: rgb(146, 224, 208);
  --ifm-code-font-size: 95%;
}
```

Now change to colors to your like!

**IMPORTANT**

It may be necessary to shutdown the `docusaurus service` and restart it.

**REFERENCE**

Note: I recommend that you check this reference, because it contains information that will help you.

https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout

Answer (score 1):

With classic theme, set your image into static/img.

-> src/css/custom.css :

```css
.hero {
    background-image: url("/static/img/back.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to file src/pages/index.js
2. add `` style={{backgroundImage: `url('/img/bg.jpg')`}} `` to  of HomepageHeader().

Because the Docusaurus is based on React, thus the css style here follows the React JSX style which uses "backgroundImage" instead of "background-image". You can check the React documents for details.

An example of src/pages/index.js:

```
function HomepageHeader() {
  const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (
    <header className={clsx('hero hero--primary', styles.heroBanner)} style={{backgroundImage: `url('/img/bg.jpg')`}}>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="hero__title">{siteConfig.title}</h1>
        <p className="hero__subtitle">{siteConfig.tagline}</p>
        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <Link
            className="button button--secondary button--lg"
            href="">
            Hire Me
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```